# Middleman won't init in windows

Tags: windows, command-line, rubygems, middleman

I'm new to middleman and I'm having big problems when I try to install it on Windows 10. It keeps giving me errors that I can't understand at all. It looks like the cli gem isn't install but it is. I've attached a picture as well.[image]

```
'require': cannot load such file --dotenv
```

Comment: Can you make sure if it is going wrong only with `init` or middleman is not properly installed by cloning a middleman site and running middleman in it. 
Here's one that you can use. 
https://github.com/roshanjossey/middleman-demo

Comment: You can also try to install `dotenv` with  `gem install dotenv`.
There can be a lot of things that might be wrong like `PATH`, dependencies etc

Comment: It's not just init, any commands with middleman doesn't work. I tried installing dotenv it says it was successful.

Comment: If you run the command `dotenv` from console, What output do you get? Maybe `dotenv` is not in correct path

Comment: Also try these. Run 'em from `devkit` folder
`ruby dk.rb init`
`ruby dk.rb install`
`gem update --system`

Comment: With all three commands I get a no such file or directory exist the first says  @ rb_sysopen - D:/.env the last two give me a load error.

Comment: Did you run it from `devkit` directory itself? Then I reckon there is problem with ruby installation itself

Comment: I've tried reinstalling ruby. The ruby init and install commands work inside the directory but dotenv still doesn't work.

Comment: So the error it is refering to is this line of code: require 'dotenv'  I'm not sure why it isn't working however.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mm-init`, `mm-build`, `mm-server`